# .NET Dispatcher, for .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Does something like `Dispatcher` exist for .NET Core?

I need to create a thread in .NET Core, and be able to send actions to be invoked on the thread. Also, I'd like to be able to use a `TaskScheduler` that can be used for `async/await` stuff.

Does this exist somewhere?

Comment: I don't see any evidence of research here.  Can you provide some links and explain how they didn't help you?

Comment: AFAIK Task.Run should still be there and function just fine, have you tried this already? Dispatcher is largely important for things like GUI applications.

Comment: ```WindowsBase``` (which is where ```Dispatcher```) is, doesn't run on .NET Core, only normal CLR.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a .NET Framework vs .NET Core issue, rather a GUI vs console app vs web service issue.  Web services don't have long-lived threads, they are request-driven.  Whatever project type you are building on .NET Core, will not have access to `Dispatcher` even if you built it with full .NET Framework.

Comment: For reasons that would take a while to explain, I have native objects that must be managed from a single thread. I also have event handlers from another source that need to be raised on the ```Dispatcher``` or ```Thread``` that created the native objects. The ```TaskScheduler.Default``` uses the thread pool. This could be done if I could reference ```WindowsBase```, but I can't. This is a long-running console service.

Comment: I'll take all these comments as a "no, it doesn't exist."

Comment: `WindowsBase` and `Dispatcher` don't exist in a console app, they're part of WPF GUI message handling.  Has nothing to do with .NET Core.

Comment: You can absolutely reference ```WindowsBase``` and use it from a command line. I have done it before. It works in unit tests as well.

Comment: I found another question where someone manually implemented what I am looking for. I will try to make something work with it.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30719366/run-work-on-specific-thread

Comment: It's still part of WPF, you've been using the console from a WPF app (which is allowed).  As for "something like", `System.Threading.SynchronizationContext` should exist, and you should be able to get a context from your thread owning the native objects, and use that for event-passing.

Comment: Can you provide me some detail? For example, if I ```Task.Run``` a thread for my native objects, how do I ensure that it will process messages indefinitely, instead of just ending? ```while(true) { await Task.Yeild(); }```?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not built-in, but my [`AsyncContext` and `AsyncContextThread` types](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx) are available in a library that would fit your need.

`AsyncContext` takes over the current thread:

```
AsyncContext.Run(async () =>
{
  ... // any awaits in here resume on the same thread.
});
// `Run` blocks until all async work is done.
```

`AsyncContextThread` is a separate thread with its own `AsyncContext`:

```
using (var thread = new AsyncContextThread())
{
  // Queue work to the thread.
  thread.Factory.Run(async () =>
  {
    ... // any awaits in here resume on the same thread.
  });
  await thread.JoinAsync(); // or `thread.Join();`
}
```

`AsyncContext` provides a `SynchronizationContext` as well as a `TaskScheduler`/`TaskFactory`.

Comment: So, If I wan't to run a "UI" thread in a console app, inside of ```AsyncCOntext.Run```, I'd get the ```SynchronizationContext```, and then do ```while(!exit) { await Task.Yeild(); }```? Then, using the ```SynchronizationContext```, I can use that to schedule tasks to be executed on that thread?

Comment: @PaulKnopf: If you want a separate thread that you can queue work do, I'd recommend using `AsyncContextThread` as shown. There's no need to capture `SynchronizationContext` - just use `AsyncContextThread.Factory` to queue work. You also don't need the `while` - the thread waits for more work until `Join`/`JoinAsync`/`Dispose` is called.

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks a lot, much appreciated!

Answer (score 10):

Just as reference: You can do like both answers of codevision and JBSnorro:

Edit .csproj file manually. The project file should look like something similar to this (For Core 3.1 use 3.1 instead of 3.0):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
        <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

If the project is unloaded, use Reload Project from the context menu.

Note: UseWPF should be added but also the "Project Sdk" type should be modified.

Comment: The ```WindowsDesktop``` part is important. Just ```<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>``` didn't work for me.

Comment: `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` with `UseWPF` worked for me with `.net6.0-windows`.

Answer (score 3):

With .NET Core 3.0 you can now use `Dispatcher` class, but it will work only on Windows, and under `netcoreapp3.0` TFM, so you cannot deploy your application on Linux or Mac.

You should add to your CSharp project following parameter

```
<PropertyGroup>
   ...
   <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
   ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

and then you can use `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher` in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the SDK reference in the .csproj is pointed to `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop`, see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/38355#issuecomment-500102808).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is one built in to .NET Core that is cross-platform,. However, most libraries that mimic WPF and WinForms on other platforms have their own dispatchers/invokers to support multithreading:

- **Avalonia's `Avalonia.Threading.Dispatcher`** - Mimics `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher`. This will probably be your most cross-platform solution ([API](https://reference.avaloniaui.net/api/Avalonia.Threading/Dispatcher/) | [Source Code](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/src/Avalonia.Base/Threading/Dispatcher.cs#L44-L56))
- **GTKSharp's `Gtk.Application.Invoke`** - Mimics WinForm's `Control.Invoke` ([Docs](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/responsive-applications/#applicationinvoke) | [Source Code](https://github.com/mono/gtk-sharp/blob/main/gtk/Application.cs#L179-L210))

There is also [Monodevelop's `DispatchService`](https://www.monodevelop.com/developers/articles/thread-management/)