# How to access the Dispatcher from a .net Core 3.1 dll (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, dispatcher, .net-core-3.1

I read: [.NET Dispatcher, for .NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41748335/net-dispatcher-for-net-core)

I'm not able to apply both solution.

- Solution of JBSnorro: Unable to find how to switch to "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop".
- Solution of codevision: I use .net Core 3.1 instead of .net Core 3.0 and a .dll instead of .exe. The result is

[image]

Any idea how to access the Dispatcher from .net-core 3.1?

**IMPORTANT** Clemens solution works great. Also, by reloading the project directly from Visual Studio has the advantage to tell you more about the problem hidden in your .csproj file. I had unmatching UseWPF with UseWpf!

Comment: It [tells you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58476275/11683) where. In the C# project file, csproj.

Comment: @GSerg, Tthanks a lot. I just realized that I had to open the .csproj file manually. But I got an error after I did the suggested solution...Perhaps because it is a dll or perhaps it is 3.1 instead of 3.0???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The project file should look like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
        <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

If the project is unloaded, use `Reload Project` from the content menu.

Comment: Do you have any idea why we can't do that from VS GUI?

Comment: I have done it that way. Choose either `WPF User Control Library (.NET Core)` or `WPF Custom Control Library (.NET Core)` as project template.

Comment: thanks a lots, I use that pretty often. I just heard that it also served a friend!

Answer (score 0):

Since a visual studio update has broke my project file my side i decide post how this should be done in 2022.

just check this checkbox in project properties.

[image]

then visual studio should rewrite your project file and add the framework wpf to your reference automaticaly.

[image]