# "System.Windows.Clipboard" not found in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.clipboard?view=netcore-3.1) the "Clipboard" class should be available in .Net Core 3.1 in the "System.Windows" namespace.

However in my .Net Core 3.1 project when using `System.Windows.Clipboard` or

```
using System.Windows;

void Method()
{
    Clipboard
}
```

in both cases I get an error saying "The type or namespace 'Clipboard', etc.".

I don't understand how to use the Clipboard class from the linked MSDN page in my .Net Core 3.1 application.

EDIT:

My question isn't answered by the linked question but by this answer (whose question is linked in the linked question, lol): https://stackoverflow.com/a/59759631/14340444

Comment: Note the *Assembly: PresentationCore.dll*, indicating that you need to reference that assembly (or, it looks like based on other comments/answers, use an Sdk which does so for you).

Comment: @JoeSewell, huh, how do I reference that assembly?

Comment: Well in this case it looks like you automatically reference it when your project file is set to use WPF. But in general, the *Assembly* line in the docs indicates which assembly contains the type, and you'll have to [reference it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/#add-a-reference-to-an-assembly). Unfortunately, the docs don't always say where that assembly is (e.g. what NuGet package it's in, or if it's on the system somewhere) but you can at least search the assembly name for help online instead of the type.

Comment: @JoeSewell, domo arigato, koza i mas! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should specifie which SDK to use in the .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  ...
</Project>
```

Comment: Actually, this is the right answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59759631/14340444