# How do you update the UI thread using .Net 6?

Tags: .net, multithreading, .net-6.0, winui-3

In .NET 4.x I could run code in a non-UI thread and update a WPF (or UWP) control in the UI thread with something like this (Messages is a string property in the ViewModel referenced by the UI which triggers OnPropertyChanged()):

```
App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => Messages += (message + Environment.NewLine)));
```

How can you access the UI thread with .NET 6?

I've looked all thru the System.Threading namespace and can't find any reference to a dispatcher similar that found in .NET 4.x.  I can find a reference to the current thread thru `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread`, but I'm not sure how to dispatch an action into that thread.

Comment: Dispatcher is not a language feature of C#, it is part of the particular framework. It works the same in WPF on .NET 6 as it did in .NET Framework.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41748335/net-dispatcher-for-net-core

Comment: .NET 6 is not .NET Core. I wouldn't use that question as reference here.

Comment: .NET5 and up are .NETCore editions, running on CoreCLR.  Microsoft renamed them to ".NET" to emphasize that is the future direction with .net

Comment: @HansPassant what I mean is that WPF has advanced since 3.1. There are no hoops to jump through to access Dispatcher.

Comment: Sorry, should have specified WinUI Desktop, I added the appropriate tag.  Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you know how to use the Dispatcher in WPF and UWP, I guess your question is about WinUI 3. For WinUI 3, use DispatcherQueue. Bisedes that, there is DispatcherHelper from Community Toolkit.